# Using erf function on shell script

Tags: shell, math, awk

I am trying to calculate some variables inside awk and most are going well. The single not working is when I try to use erf:

```
| awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, (1365*(erf(6/(2*(1/2)*((1/1250000)*$6*10*10*10*10*10*10*365)))))} '
```

Does someone know how to help in this trouble?

best,
Guilherme

Comment: Function `erf` is not defined in AWK.

Comment: @gwsmelo : on top of what Yuri mentioned, this part : `$6101010101010*365` is telling `awk` you wanna access field number `6,101,010,101,010` - 6.1 trillion

Comment: Its occurred some problem when I was writing the code here on webpage, that part inside awk would be:  $6*10*10*10*10*10*10*365

Comment: @gwsmelo : if u insist on running it over `awk`, here's a link to the CPAN source for `erf()` that may help u implement ur own : https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/Math-Erf-Approx-0.002/lib/Math/Erf/Approx.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a virtually 1-1 conversion to Perl:

```
| perl -MPOSIX=erf -ale 'print join " ", @F[0,1,2,3,4,5],
  1365*(erf(6/(2*(1/2)*((1/1250000)*$F[5]*1e6*365)))))'
```

- `-a` tells Perl to autosplit lines into array @F
- `-l` makes Perl add newline after printing
- Perl arrays are indexed from 0 (awk indexes fields from 1) so awk `$3` becomes Perl `$F[2]`
- `@F[0,1,2,3,4,5]` is a list of `$F[0]`, `$F[1]`, ...
- `join` converts a list into a string using the separator provided. I used this as it seemed a bit neater than typing: `print $F[0], " ", $F[1], " ", $F[2], " ", ...`

---

Although it has been removed in more recent versions of Perl, older versions have a helper program `a2p` to help with translation from awk (and a similar `s2p` for sed).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I was trying run the code and it is showing this message: Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 2, near ")$6"
 (Missing operator before $6?)
syntax error at -e line 2, near ")$6"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Should it works well on macbook?

Comment: The same is occurring: Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 2, near ")$5"
 (Missing operator before $5?)
syntax error at -e line 2, near ")$5"

Comment: oops, forgot to rewrite `$6` to `$F[5]`

Comment: Hi jhnc. I applied some changes and it worked well at this time.  Thank you so much. I normally use this on MATLAB T=(Tm-Ts)*erf(z./(2*sqrt(k.*(age*10^6*365))))+Ts; = T=1365*erf(6./(2*sqrt(8*10^7.*(age*10^6*365))))+0;

Comment: Then, it worked now using | perl -MPOSIX=erf -ale 'print join " ", @F[0,1,2,3,4,5],
  1365*(erf(6/(2*sqrt((8e-07)*$F[5]*1000000*365) )) )'

Comment: It is because I am doing some plots using Generic Mapping Tools at the same time, which works on shell.

Comment: @gwsmelo you mentioned Matlab. Another possibility is to work with Octave which is an open source implementation of the Matlab language, so things that you do in Matlab, might work unchanged in Octave. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there exist [`erf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/erf) function usable in C language and that GNU `AWK`'s [Writing Extensions for `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Extensions.html) allows you to

> (...)add new functions written in C or C++ to gawk using dynamically loaded
> libraries(...)

therefore I suppose this way it is possible to get `erf` function to work inside GNU `AWK`.